# Travis CI, running python3, nodejs and mono as part of the same java build

Tags: travis-ci

we have a complex multi language build, entirely driven from java.
A subset of our java unit tests actually require launching python2, python3, nodejs and mono, in the form of child processes.
Using travis-ci, out of the box, python2 works. Great!
Now I'm trying to get python3 installed, but when I add:
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get update -qq
    - sudo apt-get install -y -qq python3.4
to my yaml, the build fails, looks like travis doesn't like the syntax
Has anyone managed to install python, mono, or nodes as part of a travis java build?

Comment: Did you set `sudo: true`?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I solved the problem by providing a bunch of install steps in my yaml file
All good now

Comment: It's great that you managed to solve your problem, though it would be great if you could provide more detail on how you did solve it for others ending up here!